# Why does Eclipse not un-indent braces in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, curly-braces, auto-indent, autoformatting

I have pored over the formatting settings on Eclipse for hours and found no solution to this problem:

[Video of issue](https://jonevance.tinytake.com/sf/MzE0MzA2XzE4NjI5MDY)

When I type the opening curly brace on the line immediately following an if, else or function line the ending brace is automatically added, but neither conform to my formatting rules (i.e. the braces should be aligned with the if, else or function text).

The way it looks:

```
if (a)
  {
  }
```

The way it should look (and does after running the formatter):

```
if (a)
{
}
```

I would chalk it up to a deficiency in Eclipse except for one thing: when editing PHP, Java or C++ code it works as I'd desire; the braces are un-indented appropriately.

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/15170355/4025845

Comment: Why don't you place `{` on the same line of `if(a)`?

Comment: I grew up coding c++ and the coding standard I use is as shown above.  Looks better to me, primarily because it's what I've been looking at for decades.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Javascript formatting is exactly like that.

The `if` statement standards:

```
if (a) {
  // your code
}
```

And if you use an Array of Objects, for example:

```
var arr = [
  { prop: 'value', prop2: 5 },
  { prop: 'value', prop2: 5 }
];
```

It's working exactly as it was intended to. Take a look at this [Javascript's style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#16.1).

Comment: Eclipse allows me to set up formatting the way I like, both in JavaScript and in all other languages.  Why would it ignore my formatting preferences in favor of some standard until I explicitly ask it to apply formatting?

Answer (score 0):

This is just because the formatter is not applied after you write the code. Here is the way to do it.

1. On Eclipse, go to `Window`>`Preferences`
2. Under `JavaScript`>`Code Style`>`Formatter`, create a `New Profile`.
3. On creation of new profile or on edit, you would be shown with a window to change the format style. Go to `Braces`.
4. For `Blocks`, choose `Next Line`
5. Click `OK`. Confirm the profile and click `OK`.

Now, after you write the following:

```
if (true)
        {

        }
```

Use formatter to make changes for you, usually by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or from menu by `Source`>`Format`. You may apply formatting to selected piece of code too.

### Update

Once you have the above setting, go to `Window`>`Preferences`>`JavaScript`>`Editor`>`Save Actions`, enable `Perform the selected actions on save` and `Format source code` which would make the this operation better.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I can explicitly tell Eclipse to format according to my preferences.  In all other languages, however, the braces automatically go to the correct place when I type them, and they do not do so in JavaScript.  That is the basis for my question.